# How to make n simulations of quantile regression

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo

```
library(rqPen)
LASSO.fit(Y,X, tau=0.5, lambda=0.1, intercept=FALSE, coef.cutoff=1e-5)
```

How can i simulate this N times to get 100 sets of results? I have the below code however the computation time is too long and my PC crashes. Is this correct?

```
for (i in 1:100){
beta[i] = LASSO.fit(Y,X, tau=0.5, lambda=0.1, intercept=FALSE, coef.cutoff=1e-5)
}
```

I have also tried the following, however, the values of each beta are exactly the same for each simulation when i use lapply... I want to have different coefficients for each row of beta.

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(1:100, function(i) {
beta = LASSO.fit(Y,X, tau=0.5, lambda=0.1, intercept=FALSE, coef.cutoff=1e-5)
  return(beta)}))
```

Comment: there are some errors with assigning the betas, the answer below should fix that

Comment: even then you will always get the same result because you are regressing with the same lambda, tau and dataset. what do you actually intend to do?

Answer (score 0):

Before the `for` loop, how is `beta` defined? Likely, the crash is related with storing the output of `LASSO.fit` in `beta`. Since `LASSO.fit` returns an array, `beta` should be defined as a list:

```
beta <- vector("list", length = ncol(X))
for (i in 1:100){
beta[[i]] = LASSO.fit(Y,X, tau=0.5, lambda=0.1, intercept=FALSE, coef.cutoff=1e-5)
}
```

Using `lapply`:

```
beta <- vector("list", length = ncol(X))
beta <- lapply(1:100 , function(z) LASSO.fit(Y,X, tau=0.5, lambda=0.1, intercept=FALSE, coef.cutoff=1e-5))
```